# Razor - umbraco - get value from form and redirect

Tags: forms, razor, umbraco

I have a form in Razor I am checking for the post in a form in a Razor macro. I am checking for the form being posted with the in built IsPost variable. I need to get the value from the form (the url) and then the page to the value.

```
form action="" method="POST">                      
<select>
<option>Please Select</option>

@foreach(var item in @Model.events){
     <option value="@item.Url">@item.Name</option>   
       }
 </select>

<button id="SubmitForm" type="submit">Submit Enquiry</button>  
 <p>@Message</p>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to give your `select` an id, but you should be able to accomplish what you want by accessing the value of the `select` using `Request` collection and then redirecting to the selected url with a `Response.Redirect()`.

Example:

```
if (IsPost)
{
    string url = Request["selectId"] as string;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```